# ISE XILINX LabTool 14.7 stop the installation. Unable to Open a XZ file

Tags: zip, xilinx

The main problem is, when we try to install it, it does not even start when this message appears.

Have you ever face something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

¡SOLUTION! In windows 10 or ancients OS, Literally, you have to create a folder in your disc C called "xilinx_temporary". Then you put all your ZIP or TAR files in there. After this, unzipped your files in the same folder to open the x setup.exe file to star installation. Important detail here, in the installation path choose the same folder you create at the beginning (xilinx_temporary). So you won't have issues. The problem in the installation has to do with the name you give to the folder you install and contain the files. If the name has SPACES or ACCENTS the installation would always cause problems.

Traduce esto al español si lo necesitas en este u otro idioma.